# Is it possible to load Vue through micro frontends in Angular?

Tags: angular, vue.js, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation, angular-module-federation

As far as I know, it should be possible to support different front-end with each other through Module Federation, but I've tried for a few days and have been unable to succeed. Currently, I'm using Webpack's Module Federation to make Vue (v2) a micro frontend and have Angular try to load it, but unfortunately, I've always come up short.

Can anyone provide a basic example to show how to make Vue2 a micro frontend (considering that the team's Vue writers only use version 2, so I can only use version 2 as a practice example), and then have Angular load it?

Currently, my environment has them both set up within the Rush architecture, and I've created two fairly basic apps, one in Vue2, and one in the current version of Angular, both using Webpack federated modules.

Here's how I currently have things set up

**vue2**

> webpack.config.js

```
/* eslint-disable */

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader');

const ModuleFederationPlugin = require('webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  mode: 'development',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              esModule: false,
            },
          },
        ],
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 8081,
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './public/index.html',
      templateParameters: {
        BASE_URL: '/',
      },
    }),
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'vueApp',
      filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
      exposes: {
        './VueApp': './src/main.js',
      },
    }),
    new VueLoaderPlugin()
  ],
};
```

> package.json

```
…
"scripts": {
    …
    "webpack-serve": "webpack serve",
    …
  },
…
```

As you can see, when this Vue instance is started with Webpack, it will run on port 8081, and the information that can be exposed is vueApp/VueApp. There's basically nothing else to the whole Vue part. When it's running, I can indeed get the micro frontend instructions at http://localhost:8081/remoteEntry.js.

**Next is the Angular part:**

I've made a simple MatDialog, and when the dialog is clicked, it will open vue-dialog, and then the vue-dialog will automatically load the Vue micro frontend. That's it.

> webpack.config.js

```
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require('webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      remotes: {
        vueApp: 'vueApp@http://localhost:8081/remoteEntry.js',
      },
      name: 'angularApp',
      library: { type: 'var', name: 'angularApp' },
      filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
      shared: ['@angular/core', '@angular/common', '@angular/router']
    }),
  ],
};
```

> angular.json

```
"architect": {
  "build": {
    "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
    "options": {
      "customWebpackConfig": {
        "path": "./webpack.config.js"
      },
      ...
    },
    ...
  },
  "serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

> VueDialogComponent

```
…
ngOnInit(): void {
    from(import('vueApp/VueApp'))
    .pipe(
      tap(({ VueApp }) => VueApp.mount(this.vueContainer.nativeElement))
    )
    .subscribe();
  }
…
```

The above setup has allowed Angular to compile normally, and the compilation results are successful. However, unfortunately, the final screen is a failure, and it only shows:

> Uncaught runtime errors: × ERROR Invalid or unexpected token
> SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

In fact, I can't even find the error information because the error is contained within the automatically compiled main.js when it's launched.

That's the whole process of my testing up until now. It's mostly been frustrating, and I hope someone can give me some advice. Thanks for any help.

P.S
Additionally, as a last resort, if I continue to be unsuccessful, I may ultimately be forced to use the web component solution.